# non-www. domain not redirecting to www. domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, vhosts, mod-vhost-alias

### In a nutshell

**WORKS FINE:** *www.exampledomain.co.uk{/with-any-url}*
**GIVES 404 ERROR:** *exampledomain.co.uk{/with-any-url}*

### In detail

I am having an issue with a site running on linux/apache2 whereby 'www.' urls are working fine, however with the 'www.' removed a 404 is returned for every url. The domain shows no errors in a dnsstuff.com check, with the www and regular domain pointing to the same IP address.

When I use cmd to ping the domain and the www. domain, both resolve to the same IP and respond.

I implemented this code in a .htaccess file in the web root, which serves to prepend the 'www.' onto non-www requests:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

However, this isn't working either. The exact rewrite rules are tested and function on another site to enforce the 'www.' to be prefixed.

This is the vhosts conf file in use:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin exampleuser@exampledomain.co.uk
  ServerName  www.exampledomain.co.uk
  ServerAlias exampledomain.co.uk

  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
  DocumentRoot /home/exampleuser/public/example.co.uk/public_html
     <Directory /home/exampleuser/public/example.co.uk/public_html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
    </Directory>

  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /home/exampleuser/public/example.co.uk/log/error.log
  CustomLog /home/exampleuser/public/example.co.uk/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName exampledomain.co.uk
    Redirect permanent / http://www.exampledomain.co.uk/
</VirtualHost>
```

The server name and alias have been defined in reverse order to what is shown here (with apache restarts in-between changes) and the second vhosts entry for the 'Redirect permanent' has been added later, all to no effect.

What could be causing this behaviour? Anything else I should check? Have searched through so much material to find a solution but can't see anything wrong or missing. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I noticed that from a previous testing server instance there was another vhosts conf file in */etc/apache2/sites-enabled/* which was left behind and named **example.co.uk.conf** - the directory name used for the site that the main **exampledomain.co.uk.conf** file was pointing towards is */home/exampleuser/public/**example.co.uk**/public_html* so I checked inside and the file contained an empty vhosts declaration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
</VirtualHost>
```

When this `<VirtualHost>` section was commented out with hashes or removed, or the conf file was renamed to something other than **example.co.uk.conf**, the non-www. requests were then being routed into the correct web root just as with the www. requests and the problem was resolved.

However, I am not clear about why this **example.co.uk.conf** is chosen for requests to *exampledomain.co.uk* and not for those to *www.exampledomain.co.uk*, so if anyone can extend this answer please edit or comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, tried your rewrite rules but no effect. Seems to be the same thing as what I already have although not https-sensitive.